Pandas how to do groupby + resample + linear interpolation at once?
I have a huge dataset in a dataframe with 1 column having location name, 1 column having a depth value and then a set of other columns with values measured at those locations for those depths.
The various locations have varying depth sampling rate.
What I need to do is to resample all the locations measures to a similar sampling rate. The depth sample values themselves can be misaligned (ie 2 locations having 5m sampling rate but with samples [0,5,10,...] and [1,6,11,...] is fine).
While resampling the depth samples without an equivalent in input data must be interpolated linearly from the input sample just above and below.
I have a working slow solution resampling locations 1 by 1 and I am looking for a better solution using groupby. Below is code:

to generate fake dataset
slow working function
my current tentative new function which fails.



Import + creation of input variables and fake dataset

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

resample_interval = 5
data = [
    (2.17, 100, 1, "A"),
    (3.04, 10, 1, "A"),
    (3.91, 3, 3, "A"),
    (4.78, 5, 3, "A"),
    (5.65, 6, 5, "A"),
    (6.52, 3, 5, "A"),
    (7.39, 7, 6, "A"),
    (8.26, 9, 7, "A"),
    (9.13, 5, 8, "A"),
    (10, 3, 1, "A"),
    (10.87, 4, 3, "A"),
    (11.74, 7, 4, "A"),
    ######################
    (2.17, 100, 2, "B"),
    (3.04, 10, 5, "B"),
    (3.91, 3, 6, "B"),
    (4.78, 5, 3, "B"),
    (5.65, 6, 2, "B"),
    (6.52, 3, 4, "B"),
    (7.39, 7, 2, "B"),
    (8.26, 9, 1, "B"),
    (9.13, 5, 2, "B"),
    (10, 3, 1, "B"),
    (10.87, 4, 1, "B"),
    (11.74, 7, 5, "B"),
    ######################
    (100.0, 12, 1, "C"),
    (100.9, 12, 9, "C"),
    (101.8, 12, 6, "C"),
    (102.7, 12, 6, "C"),
    (103.6, 12, 7, "C"),
    (104.5, 14, 7, "C"),
    (105.4, 16, 7, "C"),
    (106.3, 12, 8, "C"),
    (107.2, 12, 8, "C"),
    (108.1, 12, 8, "C"),
    (109.0, 12, 3, "C"),
    (109.9, 12, 3, "C"),
    (110.8, 12, 4, "C"),
    (111.7, 12, 1, "C"),
]
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Depth", "Value1", "Value2", "locations"])
df_input = df_input.set_index("Depth", drop=True).fillna("NAN VALUE")


Old function (working but slow)
it is slow as it resamples locations 1 by 1.

def resample_location(
    location_values: pd.DataFrame, resample_interval: int
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    indx = np.arange(
        location_values.index.min(), location_values.index.max(), resample_interval
    )

    location_values_ind = location_values.reindex(
        pd.DataFrame(index=indx).index.union(location_values.index)
    ).interpolate(method="index", limit_area="inside")

    location_values_interpolated = pd.merge(
        left=pd.DataFrame(index=indx),
        right=location_values_ind,
        left_index=True,
        right_index=True,
        how="left",
    )

    location_values_interpolated[["locations"]] = location_values_interpolated[
        ["locations"]
    ].fillna(location_values["locations"].iloc[0])

    return location_values_interpolated


def resample_locations_OLD(
    locations_values: pd.DataFrame, resample_interval: int
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    locations_resampled_dfs = []
    for location in locations_values["locations"].unique():
        one_location_values = locations_values[
            locations_values["locations"] == location
        ].copy()
        df_out = resample_location(one_location_values, resample_interval)
        locations_resampled_dfs.append(df_out)
    df_output_OLD = pd.concat(locations_resampled_dfs, axis=0)
    df_output_OLD.index.name = "DEPTH"
    df_output_OLD = df_output_OLD.sort_values(by=["locations", "DEPTH"])
    return df_output_OLD


df_output_OLD = resample_locations_OLD(df_input, resample_interval)


new function (not working)
What I am after is a vectorized solution removing the locations loop to make this faster.
This is my current tentative which fails as the interpolated values returned are wrong.

def resample_locations_NEW(
    locations_values: pd.DataFrame, resample_interval: int
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # convert depth to timedelta milliseconds to be able to use pandas resampling
    locations_values["DEPTH_time"] = locations_values.index
    locations_values["DEPTH_time"] = locations_values["DEPTH_time"].apply(
        pd.to_timedelta, unit="ms"
    )
    locations_values = locations_values.set_index(["DEPTH_time"], drop=True)

    locations_values_resampled = (
        locations_values.groupby("locations")
        .resample(f"{resample_interval}ms")
        .ffill()
        .interpolate("linear", limit_area="inside")
    )

    # Transform back into initial columns
    # can be dropped instead reset_index below will re-add locations and DEPTH_time as columns
    locations_values_resampled = locations_values_resampled.drop(
        columns=["locations"]
    ).reset_index()
    # DEPTH_time back to original DEPTH column
    locations_values_resampled["DEPTH"] = (
        locations_values_resampled["DEPTH_time"].dt.microseconds / 1000
    )
    # Set DEPTH as index
    locations_values_resampled = locations_values_resampled.set_index(
        "DEPTH", drop=True
    )

    # Clean output dataframe to match old function output
    locations_values_resampled = locations_values_resampled[
        ["Value1", "Value2", "locations"]
    ]
    locations_values_resampled = locations_values_resampled.sort_values(
        by=["locations", "DEPTH"]
    )

    return locations_values_resampled


df_output_NEW = resample_locations_NEW(df_input.copy(), resample_interval)

For reference, output of both functions:
OLD FUNCTION OUTPUT - DESIRED OUTPUT :
            Value1    Value2 locations
DEPTH
2.17    100.000000  1.000000         A
7.17      5.988506  5.747126         A
2.17    100.000000  2.000000         B
7.17      5.988506  2.505747         B
100.00   12.000000  1.000000         C
105.00   15.111111  7.000000         C
110.00   12.000000  3.111111         C

NEW FUNCTION OUTPUT :
        Value1  Value2 locations
DEPTH
2.17       100       1         A
7.17         3       5         A
2.17       100       2         B
7.17         3       4         B
100.00      12       1         C
105.00      14       7         C
110.00      12       3         C

